# Ember data - One model, two endpoints

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

In ember data, if you want to fetch the collection of a model, it's convention to use this:

```
this.store.findAll('order');
```

or with a filter, this:

```
this.store.find('order', {shopId: 63});
```

So you pass the model name, and Ember-data will build the URL for you, which would look something like (depending on your adapter):

```
GET /api/orders
GET /api/orders?shopId=63
```

So this does two things

- Build the URL to fetch data from the api
- Map the collection as JavaScript objects, **using the model that you passed** as 1st argument

But what if I want to fetch orders from two URLs; `/api/orders` and `/api/new_orders` ?

The first one will work as usual: `this.store.findAll('order')`, but is there a way to override the api path that you fetch from?

Maybe something like `this.store.find('order', {path: '/new_orders'})`?

So that I can end up with a collection of objects modelled with my `order` model, but fetched from a different route

Comment: I know it's not what you want to hear but why have a different end point for something that should be a query param?

Comment: @Kitler I don't know, but I am hooking into an existing API, and I think a client-side framework should be able to adapt to the API.

Comment: It can you just need to generate an adapter for that model `ember g adapter newOrders`

Comment: I guess that would be a way around it. Is it the only way? @Kitler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a rest adapter for this store and override the findAll method. The default implementation is as such

```
findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
    var query, url;

    if (sinceToken) {
      query = { since: sinceToken };
    }

    url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, null, 'findAll');

    return this.ajax(url, 'GET', { data: query });
  }
```

`buildUrl` will return a proper endpoint for your first url. you could then parse this url and modify it to make a second request with the same data, but with to your second endpoint. Than you could merge the responses or use them separately.

Reference: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.13.5/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L398